# error on popd after goto

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%i in ( C:\folder\varibales_file.txt ) do (
   set numOfFiles=%%j
   pushd %%i
   call :Sub !numOfFiles!
   popd
)

popd
goto :EOF

:Sub numOfFiles
for /f "skip=%1 delims=" %%F in ('dir "C:\folder_path_to_delete\%%i" /b /o-d') do (
   rd /s /q "C:\folder_path_to_delete\%%i\%%F"
)
```

I got the following error: "The system cannot find the path specified."
This error Occurs as a result of insert " popd before goto"
Is someone have any idea how can i solve it?

Comment: _This error Occurs as a result of insert " popd before goto"_ How do you know that? Neither `popd` command nor `goto` one are related to paths. You _never_ should conclude something if you have not enough information... Shouldn't `C:\folder\varibales_file.txt` name be `C:\folder\variables_file.txt`?

Comment: no, it's not my real path, i changed the folders name when i wrote my code here.
anyway, whem i'm removing "popd" the error doesn't occurs

Comment: Do you know if the `for` loop is running correctly? If something makes it skip the loop, it will find a `popd` without a previous `pushd`, and yell at you.